# How to show image and words on controls?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 (As Universal app).
I have a question: Have you seen "Windows Central app for windows phone"? In this application can see hole passage and images on a website page. Here is screen shots on this application:

[image] [image]

How can I make control like this that can show images or videos on passage?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by on passage ? You want to swipe from left to right and show different content?  You want to make a multimedia slideshow which can both show images and videos ?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for reply, no i don't mean that. I want create a application for a site which is a helper site for WP users. In this site admin or writers post words with images and videos on it. i want show that posts on my application

Comment: Why not simply create a web view and use REST services to show content from your website directly to the win app?